# How to get the value from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get a value from a function inserted into my HTML.

I have tried this:

```
function testReturn(value) {    
    var ReturnValue = value; 
    return ReturnValue;  
}

html = "<div>' + testReturn(2) + ' </div>";
```

I get an error saying `Undefined`

Comment: Try using consistent quotes (either `"` and `'`, but not mixed), and declare the `html` variable.

Comment: What kind of error do you get exactly? `"<div>' + testReturn(2) + ' </div>"` will be just a string, it won't be interpreted as JavaScript code.

Comment: @andkjaer You should accept a solution to encourage people to give you helpful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing quotes and aren't declaring the variable html

If you want this to then be part of your webpage you have to write it out. To follow in what you are doing:

```
function f(x) {
    return x;
}
var html = '<div>' + f(2) + '</div>';
document.write(html);
```

A better way to do it would be with direct DOM manipulation as such:

```
var html = document.createElement('div');
html.appendChild(document.createTextNode(f(2));
document.body.appendChild(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sync your " and '.

```
html = "<div>" + testReturn(2) + "</div>";
```

Will hopefully give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
html = "<div>" + testReturn(2) + "</div>";
el.innerHTML = html;
```

el is a document element which you could get by writing something like

```
el = document.getElementById("d");
```

or since you're using jquery:

```
$("#d").append(html);
```

You might check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML